# docker-compose up throwing an error: ERROR: yaml.scanner.ScannerError: mapping values are not allowed here

Tags: docker

I'm getting this error message

```
docker-compose up
```

ERROR: yaml.scanner.ScannerError: mapping values are not allowed here
  in "./docker-compose.yml", line 1, column 13

[Docker file setup for local source code php & mysql setup [IMAGE - FYI]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tbG0.png)

Comment: Please, modify your question and paste your code, not in an image format.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, for next time, try to write your code instead linking an image. This way will be easier to do searchs, to edit and paste the answer, etc.

To solve it, try with this:

1. Locate your `docker-compose.yml` in your `\docker-vml-of-php\` folder.
2. Use this docker-compose.yml file:

```
    version: '3'

    services: 
      mySQL: 
        image: mysql:5.7
        args: 
          - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=verysecret
        environment:
          - lower_case_table_names=1
      vmlphp
        build: ./vmlphp
        volumes:
          - ./vmlphp/src:/var/www/html
        ports:
          - 80:80
        links: 
          - mySQL
        depends_on:
          - mySQL
      phpmyadmin:
        image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
        container_name: phpmyadmin
        args:
          - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=verysecret
        environment:
          - PMA_HOST=mySQL
        ports:
          - 8080:80
```

Note that it's recommended use passwords as ARGS, not ENV, to avoid it's used or accessible in container-run phase. It's more secure but is only a recommendation. If you use it as ENV it also works.

Note also that your error was because docker-compose.yml has to be placed in an upper level from every referenced folder.

I hope it works